# Currency Unicode Characters

Tags: android, ios, unicode, opengl-es

I am making a mobile game with a few in app purchases. In android for example you can download the price of the purchase so you can display it natively in your game. The issue is that because my game is opengl, I've had to come up with my own number display system. I basically have two options, I can add as many currency symbols as I can, or I can remove the currency symbols and just display the price as a number.

If I go down option A, I was wondering, are currencies which use the same symbol represented by the same unicode character? For example both the US dollar and Australian dollar use $ as the symbol. Is this character the same in unicode? Same with the Yen and Yuan they both use ¥.

I may just not display the currency symbol and use a generic image of money next to the number. There are too many currency symbols and I can't create a number font system to encompass them all.

Comment: There is no distinction between us/au/anywhere `$` and jp/cn/anywhere `¥`.  You could always display the currency *name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are currencies which use the same symbol represented by the same unicode character?

Yes